# Regex matching with a specific pattern

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me match only `::` not `:::` and replace it with newline `\n` in text editor Regex?

```
Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
Lepirudin,::Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
```

Desired Result:

```
Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
Lepirudin,
Lepirudin,:::B01AE02
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could use lookaround assertion's:

```
(?<!:)::(?!:)
```